# Is there a service for mobile data input linkable to ms-access

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I´m building a database in ms-access and I need a way for customers to input data into a mobile form that automatically updates said data in my DB

I found a way by using sharepoint, but I dont´t have the capacity in my PC for the microsoft server program needed to use sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you go about it, you will need a server (any computer with a static public IP address). There is no other way a mobile device can find your database. The easiest way is probably to set up IIS on a windows computer and use server side scripting (I use PHP) to connect to access via ODBC.

This can work with either HTML based forms (so the mobile device can use any browser) or an app that sends HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are as many approaches to this as there is flavors of ice cream.

The first part is you have to decide if the mobile device is going to store data local? If the device is to store data local, then you have to write a local application that runs on the device. This means say adopting some kind of Android development platform (or one for iOS (apple phones).

Now, of course if you go 100% web based, then a phone, tablet, computer etc. don’t matter – they all have web browsers. However, if you go with a web based application then of course such devices will not store data, or work “off line”.

So, you have to first decide the above.

If you go 100% web based, then you eliminate the need to write an application for the mobile device in question. And, then the issue becomes how to sync the data from that web site into your Access application?

Another approach which was common in the old windows “CE” or Palm Pilot days was to have the device gather data, and then sync that data with a database running on your desktop. So, you could for example have the Android phone connect to your laptop. Running the free edition of SQL server is not “too” heavy of a product, and certainly far less then running a web server on your laptop (or desktop) to JUST sync some data.

However, as noted, for this kind of setup to work, you need to run software local on the device. So, if you been building mobile applications, then this certainly is a possible road.

You could also purchase some web hosting. Many a monthly plans are slightly under $10 per month, and they all near offer SQL server, or MySQL as database options. Some web hosting companies do allow external ODBC connections, so you could link Access to tat web site and pull new records from the web “forms” that you built on the web site. (But again, this assumes asp.net or whatever web development skills on your part).

So, you have to develop either a web site, or develop some software to run on the device – take your pick.

This will really all come down to your development skills you have now (or which new ones you willing to learn).

With android development tools, there is a library that allows you to read/write to mdb files directly. So, you could copy the mdb file to an SD card, and have your android application update that mdb file and some tables directly. Then copy the mdb file from the SD card to your computer, and then read in the data. I think this would be cumbersome. And I would likely just use SQLite with Android, since it oh so well supported right now. (So, I would connection from the Android phone, and use a SQL server jdbc driver which is available to push data from the device to that local edition of sql server (jdbc is much like an ODBC standard – but it for Java).

I plan to test/try this setup soon. So, I am moving my access tables to sql server (running local on my laptop). I’ll continue to use the Access application (front end) on my laptop. I then will have my phone connect to the laptop with Wi-Fi, and sync data. As noted, going down this road since I am building some software to run on the Android. While I could have placed an mdb file on the SD card, I am going with SQLite as the database on the device. And right now, on my desktop, I have linked tables from Access working with a SQLite database anyway. But I want jdbc, as that will allow me to bridge data from the device to sql server with the least amount of effort.

So using a jdbc driver on your laptop (desktop) would eliminate the need for a web server. However, while  jdbc drivers exist for Access, if you want to connect to the jdbc driver as a "service" (and have to in this case), then because I have the lightweight SQL server express running on my laptop, then I do in a sense have  server + service running. (and that will allow use of jdbc from the phone once it is connected tot he same wi-fi network as the phone is).

So, you have a truckload of choices – much of this comes down to if you want to build + write software on the device, or build a simple web form with your favorite web development tools.